# Is it possible to change the maximum amout of files via upload in Cpanel?

Tags: upload, cpanel, php-ini

I currently have an website and I wanted to change the number of files I could upload. Already changed `upload_max_size`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` but nothing worked, it keep uploading only 20 images.

Comment: Hi in the php.ini you can set file_uploads, max_input_time, memory_limit, max_execution_time, post_max_size but all of this impact for all users no only a special user. So you have to add a limit yourself and count files upload and stored somewhere and you have to make a condition on the form upload for him and all who are in the same situation. Regards

Comment: @headmax Hi, only one user can do uploads, the admin (me), I tried changing all of those camps you said and still nothing. What did you mean with **add a limit yourself**?

Comment: Hey @Bruno Moutinho In the PHP context when you do a upload so via POST $_FILE via form page, or using ftp upload via form page depend of your context but cpanel is open source and writing in PHP https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcpanel/ and this a script can be modified but if don't known what it's your priority ... and for only one person i think you should add the limit into the php.ini and same on the server ftp or SSH if he got an access. http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php  regards.